# VScode with Latex Workshop aint generating Table of contents/list of figures etc

Tags: table-of-contents, vscode

I already wrote a few Tex documents in overleaf and the table of contents and list of figures always generated fine. Now, because of recommendations, I switched to VScode and I installed everything as told. Now even when I insert my recent codes VScode does not generate the list of figures/table of content, but when I insert my code pin overleaf, overleaf generates it quite fine. Following my used packages and the commands I use for generating the table/list.

```
\documentclass[
  oneside,  a4paper,
    11pt,
    parskip=half, 
    headings=standardclasses,
    numbers=noenddot, 
    headsepline, 
    captions=tableheading, 
    ngerman 
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,microtype}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[locale=DE,separate-uncertainty=true, per-mode=fraction,group-separator={}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,interval,physics}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikzpagenodes,caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,makecell}
\captionsetup{labelfont={bf,sf}}
\usepackage{xcolor,xurl}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor={red!50!black},citecolor={blue!50!black},urlcolor={blue!80!black}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor={red!50!black},citecolor={blue!50!black},urlcolor={blue!80!black}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[margin=1in,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}

...

{\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\tableofcontents 
\listoffigures 
\listoftables} 

...
\section{...}
```

[image: picture of the generated ToC/LoF]

Comment: did you compile twice?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer no matter how often I compile the document it still won't compile, but in the bottom right corner pops-up an error "recipe terminated with error" "source: Latex Workshop (extension)". When I open the compiler log though I cant find out the reason for the error.

Comment: Use some other editor or compile on the command line.